# Django group by and count(*), includes zero counts

Tags: django, group-by

```
class Author(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Book(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   author = models.ForeignKey(Author,related_name='book' on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want to display the number of books in each author (include zero counts).
My code:

```
Book.objects.filter(is_deleted =False).values('author').annotate(num=Count('id'))
```

but it only returns values greater than zero and lost many authors.
How can I get result like this:

```
author1:0,
author2:1,
author3:2,
```

Please help me and thanks in advance ^^.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try like this(using [**`related objects`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/)):

```
authors = Author.objects.annotate(
    book_count=Count(
        'book',
        filter=Q(book__is_deleted=False)
    )
)
authors.values('name', 'book_count')
```